# rails test and development databases are in different schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, performance, postgresql

I want to make benchmark tests but when I run

```
rake test:benchmark
```

I'm taking this kinds of errors

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "contests" does not exist
LINE 5:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"contests"'::regclass
                                      ^
:             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                   pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
            FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
              ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
           WHERE a.attrelid = '"contests"'::regclass
             AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
           ORDER BY a.attnum
```

it must be a migration error. But when I run

```
rake db:migrate
```

anything happens. I dropped test database and I run

```
rake db:test:clone
```

after that run again benchmark but it is still giving error.

my database.yml file like this

```
development:
      adapter: postgresql
      encoding: unicode
      host: localhost
      database: dummy_development
      pool: 5
      username: postgres
      password: dum

    test:
      adapter: postgresql
      encoding: unicode
      host: localhost
      database: dummy_test
      pool: 5
      username: postgres
      password: dum

    production:
      adapter: postgresql
      encoding: unicode
      host: localhost
      database: dummy_production
      pool: 5
      username: postgres
      password: dum
```

also when I backup development database and restore test database with it I take errors. I think database schema's different but I do not know how to do they same. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Not too sure if this would fix the problem, but it seems like you only migrated your development database.  Rails typically has 3 environments, production, development and test.

When you run `rake test:benchmark` or any `rake test` it is using the test database defined in database.yml.

Running `rake db:migrate`  only migrates the database for development.  You must tell rake which environment to run in if you want to migrate the test database.  `RAILS_ENV=test` is the way to tell Rails which environment to run the task in.

From the look of your error, it looks as if the tables don't exist in your test database, so my suggestion is to try running:

`rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test`

Comment: It would be useful if you could expand on how this answers the question.

Comment: Thanks! Much more helpful for others finding this question now.

Answer (score 1):

When you run test:benchmark it reloads the test DB from the schema.

Looks like the "contests" table is missing.  Is that in your schema file?

You can also try connecting to the test environment to see that state of that DB:

```
rails console test
```

Comment: When I run rake test:benchmark i take this error still. when i open the test console and check for "Contest" model there is no problem. It is weird.